# How to add new args data in $wp_customize->add_setting?

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

What I'm trying to achieve is to add new args ( **output** ) as below:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'modular_header_main_border_bottom_color', array(
        'default'    => '#e9ecef',
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'output'     => array(
            array(
                'element'  => 'body',
                'property' => 'background-color',
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

And, get *output* array in front and enqueue it as a valid CSS. Till now, 
I've tried achieve the same using *customize_dynamic_setting_args* hook which works fine in Customizer. But the problem is data from it is not accessible in frontend. 
https://pastebin.com/AEdmPJDV

I guess there should be another way of doing same.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for

```
$args = array(
    'default'    => '#e9ecef',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
);

if ( something() ) {
    $args['output'] = array(
        array(
            'element'  => 'body',
            'property' => 'background-color',
        ),
    );
}

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'modular_header_main_border_bottom_color', $args );
```

We are first creating an array for arguments. Later we are pushing a key value to that array with some conditions.

Comment: Do you mind explaining the code?